# How to stop Raspbian leafpad from leaving behind the message: Failed to load module “libcanberra-gtk-module”

Tags: raspbian

Every time I use leafpad it all seems to work just fine, 
but on the console it leaves behind the error message:

> Failed to load module “libcanberra-gtk-module”

How do I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Cross-posted this to answer a 4-yr-old question at:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/208431/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out all it wanted was to have that module installed for some reason.

Simply entering

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

makes that error message go away completely.